# Pause threads based on their ID

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I'm wanting to only accept output from threads 1 at a time. I have a Boolean arraylist which holds all values as false bar 1. This true position then relates to a thread by its ID number. This is the only thread which is 'allowed' to output, I want to put all others into sleep until their respective arraylist number calls them. Here is my code so far

```
                int threadPos = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    if(turn.get(threadPos)==true) //see if value in arraylist is true
                    {//if so accept its input, then increment count
                        userInput = in.readLine();
                        System.out.println(userInput);
                        turn.set(threadPos, false);
                        if(threadPos < turn.size())
                        {
                            threadPos++;
                            turn.set(threadPos, true);
                        } else {
                            threadPos = 0;
                            turn.set(0, true);
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Put all other threads to sleep
                    }

                }
```

Thanks

Comment: Before we start to try to solve a possible [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) please tell us the motivation behind your desired program design and behavior.

Comment: Ill try and shorten the explanation. I have a client and server. Each client connects to the server on a different thread. The client can type (in the command line) this gets sent to the server, then some other stuff happens. It at this point when I only want 1 client to send to the server at a time. When they have typed the next client can but no-one else, then the 3rd and so on. I hope this makes sense

Comment: So this is server code above or client code? Trying to stop a server thread that reads client input will not stop the clients from trying to send data. I'm still very confused.

Comment: This is taken from the server. The clients typed code is userInput